# Regex.Matches error cannot convert from char to string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I have this c# code in NET4.5 to read a text file which looks like this:

```
1   3          10.1144881901           48.8578515599          340.2980957031           -3.9997586182           -2.0398821492          -56.6352938643
2   1          10.1137751593           48.8575005060          401.4981384277          -11.7762306910            3.4075851669          -92.5498187137
```

and I want to change the 5th row numbers

This is the code

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
     String pattern = @"(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)";
     foreach (var expression in line)
         foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(expression, pattern))
         {                        
            double value = Double.Parse(m.Groups[5].Value);
         }            
}
```

And I get these compile errors:

error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(string, string)' has some invalid arguments

error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'string'

Comment: You could just use `string.Split` instead of a regular expression.

Comment: but the there are tabs and spaces between the numbers and I don't know if split works with a variable number of tabs or spaces between numbers.

Comment: Jonesopolis's answer is, more or less, what you want.

Comment: You can use `line.Split(new[] {' ','\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` if the values in the columns are never empty.  Or more likely just split on tabs and trim the spaces if needed assuming this is a tab separated fixed width format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get rid of your outer foreach:

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
     String pattern = @"(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)";

     foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(line, pattern))
     {                        
        double value = Double.Parse(m.Groups[5].Value);
     }            
}
```

you were iterating over your string, which is a char array.